# Are these Java long integer or BigInteger format numbers? IP2Location csv database

Tags: java, biginteger, ip2location

I have never used long integer or BigInteger format numbers in my Java code, and this aspect of the IP2Location databases does not appear to be documented. I need to know which it is, so that I can write some simple code to compare numbers for greater that or equal. Here are a couple of lines of data from the file...

```
"281470698522624","281470698524671","CN","China","Guangdong","Guangzhou"
"281470698524672","281470698528767","JP","Japan","Tokyo","Tokyo"
```

EDIT: The two numbers at the  beginning of each line represent a range of IP addresses that are located in the city identified by the last 4 entries on the line. I convert my IP address to a decimal notation following a known algorithm, then search thru the file sequentially until I find a second number that is greater than or equal to my IP. Then I have the location data :)
QED

Hope you can help,
***Mick*** :)

Comment: `long` is restricted to numbers between -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807, inclusive - `BigInteger`  - 2^2147483647 (exclusive) to +2^2147483647 (exclusive) -- posted numbers are well within the `long` range

Comment: What is the algorithm that you are talking about? That is needed to understand the question.

Comment: They're just integers, plain and simple. Are you asking if they'll fit in a java `long`?

Answer (score 1):

It [**is documented**](https://www.ip2location.com/database/db4-ip-country-region-city-isp):

```
ip_from INT(10)  / Decimal(39,0)    First IP address in netblock.
ip_to   INT(10)  / Decimal(39,0)    Last IP address in netblock.
```

Given that your samples consist of more than 10 digits, you have the IPv6 version of DB4. Which would have been a good thing to mention in your question. These numbers can grow very large - larger than `long` can support (which can go as far as `Long.MAX_VALUE`, which is `2^63-1`, far less than 39 nines, which is as far as these numbers can theoretically go.

You could represent them with `BigInteger`, or 2 longs (IPv6 addresses are 128 bits long, and longs are 64 bit, so 2 longs can do it - given that this is basic IPv6 info, I don't think it's useful or necessary for IP2Location to mention this. In fact, calling it 'decimal(39,0)' is a bit of a daft way to state 'IPv6 address as a single number stated in decimal'. At any rate, they represent InetAddresses, so you might want to use the class that actually describes what it is, namely, [`InetAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/InetAddress.html).

Comment: Thank you. I did not find that as I did not go out of the free data base sections :)

Answer (score 0):

I found methods for everything that I need in this...

```
IPAddress Java library
https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/
```

The manager of this library has posted this link in a few of the threads on this topic.

Answer (score -1):

You asked:

> Are these Java long integer or BigInteger format numbers?

They are `long` values.

In Java, you can see the `min` and `max` by using setting `MIN_VALUE` and `MAX_VALUE` for each of `Byte, Short, Integer, Long, Float, and Double`.  You can see how many bits wide they are by using SIZE.

Examples:

```
System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println(Long.SIZE);
```

prints

```
9223372036854775807
64
```

Check out [Double](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html) and [Float](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Float.html) for more constants such as MIN_EXPONENT and PRECISION.

For requirements exceeding those types, check out [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) and [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Also, if you want to find the maximum number of digits, in a `long` (similar for `int, short, or byte`, you can do the following:

```
double digitsInLong = (Long.SIZE*Math.log(2))/Math.log(10);
System.out.println(digitsInLong);
```

prints

```
19.265919722494793
```

This says there can be between `19` and `20` digits.  All longs can have `19` digits but some longs with `20` will overflow the `63` bit size limit for positive numbers.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the *[Long#parseLong](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String))* method, to convert a *String* value to a  *[long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)* primitive data-type.

```java
String[] a = { "281470698522624","281470698524671","CN","China","Guangdong","Guangzhou" };
String[] b = { "281470698524672","281470698528767","JP","Japan","Tokyo","Tokyo" };
long a0 = Long.parseLong(a[0]);
long a1 = Long.parseLong(a[1]);
long b0 = Long.parseLong(b[0]);
long b1 = Long.parseLong(b[1]);
System.out.println("a0 = " + a0);
System.out.println("a1 = " + a1);
System.out.println("b0 = " + b0);
System.out.println("b1 = " + b1);
```

Output

```
a0 = 281470698522624
a1 = 281470698524671
b0 = 281470698524672
b1 = 281470698528767
```

If you'd like to use the *[BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html)* class, you can simply supply the *String* value as the parameter of the constructor method.

```java
BigInteger a0 = new BigInteger(a[0]);
BigInteger a1 = new BigInteger(a[1]);
BigInteger b0 = new BigInteger(b[0]);
BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger(b[1]);
```